# Solving variable may not have been initialized error

Tags: java

Here is my method. For `iOption ==2`, it says `iScore1` `iScore2` and `iScore3` haven't been initialized even though they are initialized through `iOption == 1.` The program must first Use iOption 1 before using iOption2

```
while (iOption != '6')
{
    if(iOption == 1)
    {
        iScore1 = Utility.testScore();
        iScore2 = Utility.testScore();
        iScore3 = Utility.testScore();

        Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
        Utility.clearScreen();

        iOption = Utility.menuOption();
    }

    if(iOption == 2) 
    {


                System.out.println("\n\tScore 1: " + iScore1);
                System.out.println("\n\tScore 2: " + iScore2);
                System.out.println("\n\tScore 3: " + iScore3);

                System.out.println("\n");

                Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
                Utility.clearScreen();

                iOption = Utility.menuOption();


    }

        if(iOption == 3)
        {



                dGrade = Utility.calcAverage(iScore1, iScore2, iScore3);


                System.out.println("Average: " + dGrade);
                System.out.println("\n");

                Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
                Utility.clearScreen();

                iOption = Utility.menuOption();

        }

        if(iOption == 4)
        {



                cLetter2 = Utility.letterGrade(dGrade);

                System.out.print("Letter grade: " + cLetter2);


                System.out.println("\n");

                Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
                Utility.clearScreen();

                iOption = Utility.menuOption();

        }

        if(iOption == 5)
        {

                    Utility.calcGPA();

                    Utility.pressEnterToContinue();
                    Utility.clearScreen();

                    iOption = Utility.menuOption();

        }

}
```

Comment: What if your loop never enters iOpiont == 1?

Comment: you may want to use an enum instead of a raw integer to select what action to take. then you can account for every possible value more elegantly

Answer (score 1):

No, it has't been initialized because your initialization is within an `if` statement. What happens if `iOption=2`? The value of `iScore1` is undefined then, because first `if` statement is skipped. The code within it is not executed. I assume you wanted to put those initialization lines before the first `if`.

Answer (score 1):

the reason may be due to  `iScore1 iScore2 and iScore3` are local variables meaning its declared in ssome method and its not initialized.As RJ has pointed out  *since the assignment is conditional, it gives the not initialized error in the second if condition* so you need to initialize it first

Either initialize it to some value or make these as class variables
If you make these as class variables then this will be initialized with their default values.
For example if these are `int` then it wil be initialized to `0` or if these are `Strings` then these will be initialized to `null`

Comment: *the reason may be due to iScore1 iScore2 and iScore3 are local variables* - So what if they are local variables in the method?! They are still accessible throughout the method. Just that they are initialized conditionally. Variable scope is not a problem here. Conditional assignment is.

Comment: @R.J I mean these variables are with in some method

Comment: @R.J I dont think if varibales declared in methods but not initialized will be accessible in the above loop.Am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly. Its in some method and within that method, since the assignment is conditional, it gives the not initialized error in the second `if` condition. I suggest you edit your answer accordingly!

Comment: They will be. Why won't they be?! If you can't access an uninitialized variable, what's the point creating them? Its just that you can't use them to print or do some manipulation. It first needs to be initialized, and then, you can print it out(as in OP's case).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing the initialization in a `if` statement. This `if` block will only execute when `iOption==1`. If this condition fails and it enters `iOption==2` , it will have to print `iScore1` etc without a known initial value. Therefore you need to intialize them before the `if` somewhere. Just set it to `0` in-case you don't need it to have any other value.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not given initial default values. Thus, you must assign a value before you use a local variable.

I your case you are initializing only inside if condition.

Give a similar try with "obvious" condition like if(1>0) {}. The compiler compiles and not makes the analysis of your code. While for human it is obvious that something will happen, the java compiler have no code to detect such cases, neither it is specified by java syntax. So you're expecting from the compiler the AI it doesn't have, to keep the compiling clear, predictable and fast.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831974/java-local-variable-is-initialized-still-get-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

You must have declared something like this somewhere else in your code:

```
int iScore1;
int iScore2;
int iScore3;
```

Instead, you should do:

```
int iScore1 = 0;
int iScore2 = 0;
int iScore3 = 0;
```

Basically, you need to first initialize the values before using them. Otherwise, you will get the *Variable may not have been intialized* error.

You might argue that these values would have been initialized inside the `iOption == 1` branch which would always be executed before the `iOption == 2` branch. Unfortunately, the compiler is not as smart as you, thus giving the complaint.

Comment: But whenever Option 2 is ran it displays score 1, 2, and 3 to be 0.

Comment: @user2909717 No, since Option 1 is always run before Option 2, score 1, 2, 3 will be updated in Option 1. By the way, what does `Utility.testScore()` return?

Comment: public static int testScore()
 {
  int iScore;
  
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("\n\tEnter an integer test score: ");
  iScore = kb.nextInt();
  
  return iScore;
 }//end testScore

Comment: @user2909717 OK. Assume Option 1 is always run before Option 2. When Option 2 is run, it should display score 1, 2, 3 as provided by the user.

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought too. But since i had to set it equal to 0 at the beginning of the method it displays as 0 and is not getting updated.

Comment: @user2909717 Did you put them inside the while loop or outside? It should be outside of the while loop.

Comment: It's not in a while loop.

Comment: @user2909717 Can you post more relevant code? The current code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its not javaScript, to make it auto initialize. you need to initialize iScore1 iScore2 and iScore3 at class level or method level declaration.