# What does "Variable might not have been initialized" mean?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

```
public static double[] processUserInput(String data) {
        String[] arrayInString;
        double[] arrayInDouble;
        int length;

        if( data.contains(",") ) {
            arrayInString = data.split(",");

            length = arrayInString.length;

            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arrayInDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble( arrayInString[i] );
            }
        }

        return arrayInDouble;

    }
```

I am using Netbeans and the compiler is saying that variable `arrayInDouble` might not have been initialized. What does that mean?

Comment: String[] arrayInString;
 double[] arrayInDouble;
You have not intialized these array that' why you are getting warning that variable may not be initailized.

Comment: when I do this 'double[] arrayInDouble = new double[]{};' it fixs the problem, but arrayInString does not complain about it?!

Comment: @Joshua The only time you ever use `arrayInString` is when `data.contains(",")` is true, and in that case, you initialize before using. Thus, the compiler can be sure that you initialize that variable before use. The problem here is that if `data.contains(",")` is false, you're using `arrayInDouble` without initializing (but you wouldn't be using `arrayInString`, hence why it doesn't complain in that way about that variable).

Comment: @Dennis Meng Do you mean because I am returning arrayInDouble at the end so I have to assign something to the variable? So the returning behaviour is calling 'using the variable'? or I am wrong?

Comment: Pretty much. In the case with the return, what are you returning if the variable isn't initialized?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable may not have been initialized"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895175/variable-may-not-have-been-initialized) among numerous others. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532591/variable-may-not-have-been-intialized covering conditionals

Comment: Stackoverflow is hard :( even though there is duplicate version doesn't mean I dont need more explaination...

Comment: There are so many questions titled `Variable may not have been initialized`, or something similar, that it was difficult to clean up your title. Seriously, before posting a question, go through the other answers (especially the ones that come up when you start typing you question) and **read** them. Stackoverflow is not a random person you ask for an answer. Before asking, see if there is already an answer to your question. If you want more explanation, find some other forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[] arrayInString;
```

This is not initialized but you provide a value (`arrayInString = data.split(",");`) before referring to it so there is no complaint.

```
    double[] arrayInDouble;
```

This is also uninitialized. If the input does not contain a comma, you skip all the code and then attempt to return the value of `arrayInDouble`. The warning says that when you execute the `return`, `arrayInDouble` may not have a value.

Answer (score 1):

In this

```
String[] arrayInString;
double[] arrayInDouble;
```

you are just declaring them, before you use them, you also need to initialize:

```
String[] arrayInString = new String[length1];
double[] arrayInDouble = new double[length2];
```

where `length` is the length of the array.

**PS:** There are other ways to initialize them, for example:

```
double[] arrayInDouble = {1.1, 2.2}; // The length of the array will be the number of elements in brackets
```

Comment: Wired thing: 'String[] arrayInString = new String[3];' it complains 'assigned value never used'...

Comment: String is an object, double is primitive, if you're array is of java.lang.Double it will exhibit the same behaviour

Comment: @Joshua Is that an error? or a warning? If it's a warning it just means that you are not doing anything with the array `arrayInString`, since this is just for test you can ignore that **warning**.

Comment: @Christian Still might want to point out that it isn't ideal to ignore warnings in the long run though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize them (assign some value) before using them.

Comment: when I do this 'double[] arrayInDouble = new double[]{};' it fixs the problem, but arrayInString does not complain about it. Why is that?

Comment: @Joshua: Because you are assigning it a value here `arrayInString = data.split(",");`

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any values to these variables

```
 String[] arrayInString;
 double[] arrayInDouble;
```

These variables are local variables so they need to be initialized before using as they will not get any default value for them.

Comment: I would like to know the mistake I have done while posting this answer.